# Get vertices with a simpler format

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, janusgraph

Is there a way to get a list of vertices with a simpler format?
Currently, the following query:

```
g.V().has(label, 'Quantity').has('text', '627 km');
```

returns an object like this:

```
{
   "id": 42545168,
   "label": "Quantity",
   "type": "vertex",
   "properties": {
       "sentence": [
       {
          "id": "pkbgi-pbw28-745",
          "value": "null"
       }
       ],
       "updated_text": [
       {
          "id": "pk9vm-pbw28-5j9",
          "value": "627 km"
       }
       ],[...]
```

And when I get a list of edges it is formatted in a simpler format:

```
g.E().has(label, 'locatedAt').has('out_entity_id','41573-41579');
```

returns:

```
{
  "id": "ozfnt-ip8o-2mtx-g8vs",
  "label": "locatedAt",
  "type": "edge",
  "inVLabel": "Location",
  "outVLabel": "Location",
  "inV": 758008,
  "outV": 872520,
  "properties": {
      "sentence": "Bolloré is a corporation (société anonyme) with a Board of Directors whose registered offi ce is located at Odet, 29500 Ergué-Gabéric in France.",
      "in_entity_id": "41544-41548",
      "score": "0.795793",
      "out_entity_id": "41573-41579"
  }
}
```

How so?
Is there a way to get vertices formatted this way?

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to rather than have your query return the whole vertex, return the specific properties that you are interested in. For example the vertex ID or some selected properties that you are interested in or a valueMap. Otherwise what you will get back is essentially everything. This is really the same as in SQL trying to not do a "select *" but selecting only what you really care about.

Edited to add an example that returns the IDs of matching vertices.

```
g.V().has(label, 'Quantity').has('text', '627 km').id().fold()
```

Will yield a result that looks like this

```
{"requestId":"73f40519-87c8-4037-a9fc-41be82b3b227","status":{"message":"","code":200,"attributes":{}},"result":{"data":[[20608,28920,32912,106744,123080,135200,139296,143464,143488,143560,151584,155688,155752,159784,188520,254016,282688,286968,311360,323832,348408,4344,835648,8336,1343616,12352]],"meta":{}}}
```